# задержка анимации storyboard xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

привет подскажите как сделать что бы при срабатывании триггера (движение мыши) анимация воспроизводилась с задержкой.
вот код

```
<Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseMove">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetProperty="Opacity" TargetName="Controls">
                        <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:4"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте например

```
BeginTime="0:0:1"
```